# How can I uses Sesame's RDFXMLParser in JRuby?

Tags: java, xml, jruby, rdf, sesame

I am not very experienced in Java and JRuby but need to parse RDF data using Sesame's [RDFXMLParser](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/2.2.4/apidocs/org/openrdf/rio/rdfxml/RDFXMLParser.html) in JRuby and my python-minded brain just does not want to get into it. I have problems translating the Java example into JRuby. At first I don't know how to define the RDFHandler in a way it would make sense. I also don't get why the parse methods needs a Reader and an URI as I only want to parse local file.

I would highly appreciate example code in JRuby. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the JRuby-specific part of your question, but as for your confusion over how to invoke the `parse()` method: if you only want to parse a local file, you would normally do that by simply creating a `java.io.FileInputstream` object for your file and providing that to the parser.